# How do I set Session timeout in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I can use the Session fine, but I don't know how to control the timeout. Can someone help me? I would like to set the timeout in my web.config. Here is my code:

```
Session["u"] = "ha";
```

How can I extend the timeout?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the timeout in sessionState section; value is minutes until timeout

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried Session.Timeout?

this will set the timeout programmatically for all session variable though

Regards,
Shailesh